# Bootstrap select drop down not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a js plugin called "Bootstrap Select" but when I use it, the drop down comes down, but its only about 5px high.

How do I get it to drop down normally?

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```html
<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>1st Degree</option>
  <option>2nd Degree</option>
</select>
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQorjb

EDIT: I've come to realize that most bootstrap things aren't working.

I can't get tabs, pills, or accordions working either. But overall, bootstrap IS working on the site. So I don't get it.

Comment: Looks like a CSS issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not including the [plugin's CSS](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

Look at [your CodePen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOqbPo).

Comment: It works on the codepen, but not on my site. :( http://project8.byethost22.com/belts.php

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Bootstrap-select CSS file and your other problems could stem from your dependencies not being stacked correctly.

In this order just like the example.

CSS Files

- BootstrapCSS
- Bootstrap-select CSS
- Custom CSS

JS Files

- jQuery
- BootstrapJS
- Bootstrap-select JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <select class="selectpicker">
    <option>1st Degree</option>
    <option>2nd Degree</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```